# HTML5 video in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, ffmpeg, h.264, mpeg-4

I have 3 copies of a video:

> Raw AVI
>
> Encoded .mp4 (h.264 video and mp3 audio)
>
> Encoded .ogv, encoded with oggtheora

My HTML 5 player runs in Firefox 14, Chrome 19 and Opera 12, it fails however in, you guessed it.. Internet Explorer 9. As far as I know the h.264 file should be picked up and play, however it's not.

```
<video class="vid" width="550" height="400" controls>
    <source src="test/charlie.mp4" type="video/mpeg" /> 
    <source src="test/charlie.ogv" type="video/ogg" /> 
    Nope.
</video>
```

Any ideas?

And please take this picture as a sign of my gratitude

[image: rageface]

For whoever asked and then deleted their comment:

```
htdocs/html5$ ls
    index.php  test
htdocs/html5/test$ ls
     charlie.avi  charlie.mp4  charlie.ogv
```

Comment: Have you read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410106.aspx ? http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/ie9/

Comment: I've seen the msdn link, not the second though. If it was up to me I'd ditch the IE support right now but unfortunately I need to find a html solution (or at least try before falling back to flash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `type="video/mp4"` instead of `type="video/mpeg"` ?

```
<video class="vid" width="550" height="400" controls>
    <source src="test/charlie.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
    <source src="test/charlie.ogv" type="video/ogg" /> 
    Nope.
</video>
```

I used to and never had problems with IE9, can come from here.

Comment: You're welcome... I was about joking on the fact "you finally found Charlie", but woe is me, this joke is ruined by the translation... (Charlie is the french version of Wally)